Adding liquidity are failed not able to access slot0 values
function addLiquidity(AddLiquidityParams memory params)
internal
returns (
uint128 liquidity,
uint256 amount0,
uint256 amount1,
IUniswapV3Pool pool
)
{
PoolAddress.PoolKey memory poolKey =
PoolAddress.PoolKey({token0: params.token0, token1: params.token1, fee: params.fee});
    pool = IUniswapV3Pool(PoolAddress.computeAddress(factory, poolKey));

    // compute the liquidity amount
    {
        (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = pool.slot0();
        uint160 sqrtRatioAX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(85140);
        uint160 sqrtRatioBX96 = TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(85200);

        liquidity = LiquidityAmounts.getLiquidityForAmounts(
            5602277097478614198912276234240,
            sqrtRatioAX96,
            sqrtRatioBX96,
            params.amount0Desired,
            params.amount1Desired
        );
    }
    emit test("addedd liquidty successfuuly");
    emit test45(liquidity,
         amount0,
         amount1,
         pool);
    (amount0, amount1) = pool.mint(
        params.recipient,
        params.tickLower,
        params.tickUpper,
        liquidity,
        abi.encode(MintCallbackData({poolKey: poolKey, payer: msg.sender}))
    );

    require(amount0 >= params.amount0Min && amount1 >= params.amount1Min, 'Price slippage check');
return(liquidity,
         amount0,
         amount1,
         pool);

}

}
i'm unable to get the           (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = pool.slot0();  sqrtPrice96 from the slot0
i want to add liquidty in uniswap v3 using smart contract.. but my transaction are reverted..

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

are you sure the pool is initialized?  If you're adding liquidity to a brand new pool idk if you can get slot0

Also why do you need slot0 you're not even using it in the code you provided
